# Crystal report not displaying in design page

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports-2010

I have my crystal report added in html page but it is not showing in desgn page got error 
Use the reportsource id property to show the reportsource control.
Kindly suggest me

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true"
        CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default._Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"   Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web"TagPrefix="CR"%>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <title>Crystal Report Sample</title>

  </head>

  <body>

  <form id="form1"runat="server">

    <div>
    <CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CrystalReportViewer1" runat="server" AutoDataBind="true" ReportSourceID="CrystalReportSource1" />  
    <CR:CrystalReportSource ID="CrystalReportSource1" runat="server"></CR:CrystalReportSource>

    </div>

  </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the error that crystal report shows?

Comment: Something's wrong with this question.. ReportSourceID in set in CrystalReportViewer